# Appending to existing Excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

Looking for some suggestion on possible another way I might go about doing this. I have a CSV that has parcel ID I need to look up. I take the information from the ID's and insert that data into an existing excel file which is a template. Once the data from the search is entered into the template, I need to save it to a specific folder.

```
import os import csv import openpyxl from openpyxl import load_workbook from openpyxl.styles import Alignment from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import time import pandas as pd

def run_search(input_csv, output_excel, output_folder):
    # Load input CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(input_csv)
    
    # Check if the output Excel file exists, and return an error if it doesn't
    if not os.path.exists(output_excel):
        print(f"Error: Output file {output_excel} does not exist.")
        return
    
    # Load the output Excel workbook and worksheet
    workbook = load_workbook(output_excel)
    worksheet = workbook['Justification Worksheet']
    
    # Loop over each row in the input CSV and perform the search
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        parcel_number = row['Tax_ID']
        search_results = perform_search(parcel_number)
        if search_results:
            # Append the search results to the output Excel worksheet
            append_search_results(search_results, worksheet, index)

            # Save the search results to a CSV file in the specified output folder
            save_search_results(search_results, output_folder)

    # Save the changes to the output Excel file
    workbook.save(output_excel)

def perform_search(parcel_number):
    """Perform the search on the given parcel number and return the results."""
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://esearch.mobilecopropertytax.com/")
        time.sleep(5)
        search_bar = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="keywords"]')
        search_bar.send_keys(parcel_number)
        search_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/span/button')
        search_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        search_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr')
        search_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        element = soup.find('th', text='Parcel Number:')
        parcel_number = element.find_next_sibling().text
        element = soup.find('th', text='Name:')
        name = element.find_next_sibling().text
        element = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='th' and 'Address:' in tag.text)
        address = element.find_next_sibling().text
        parts = address.split(',')
        city = parts[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]
        state_zip = parts[1].strip()
        state, zip_code = state_zip.split(' ')
    except:
        print("An error occurred while performing the search.")
        return None
    finally:
        driver.quit()
    return [parcel_number, name, address, city, state, zip_code]

def append_search_results(search_results, worksheet, row_number):
    """Append the search results to the output Excel worksheet."""
    try:
        # Select the cells based on the row number
        cell1 = worksheet[f'C{row_number+6}'] # Parcel Number
        cell2 = worksheet[f'C{row_number+9}'] # Name
        cell3 = worksheet[f'C{row_number+10}'] # Address
        cell4 = worksheet[f'C{row_number+11}'] # City
        cell5 = worksheet[f'E{row_number+11}'] # State
        cell6 = worksheet[f'G{row_number+11}'] # Zip code

        # Set the values of the cells
        parcel_number, name, address, city, state, zip_code = search_results
        cell1.value = parcel_number # Parcel Number
        cell2.value = name # Name
        cell3.value = address # Address
        cell4.value = city # City
        cell5.value = state # State
        cell6.value = zip_code # Zip code

        # Modify the format and alignment of the cells
        cell1.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
        cell2.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
        cell3.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
        cell4.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
        cell5.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)
        cell6.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center', shrink_to_fit=False)

    except:
        print("An error occurred while appending the search results to the Excel worksheet.")

def save_search_results(search_results, output_folder):
    """Save the search results to a CSV file in the specified folder."""
    filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{search_results[0]}.csv")
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Parcel Number', 'Name', 'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip Code'])
        writer.writerow(search_results)

# Specify the input CSV file, output Excel file, and output folder input_csv = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\parcel_numbers.csv' output_excel = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\EJW Template.xlsx' output_folder = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\EJW Jeffereson Co Text'

# Run the search and append the results to the specified output Excel file and CSV files in the output folder run_search(input_csv, output_excel, output_folder)
```

The issue I have is getting it to append the information to the template. It seems to just be creating new excel files with the information instead of inserting it into the template and then saving it as a new file.

Getting back this error:

```
An error occurred while appending the search results to the Excel worksheet.
```

Comment: probably easier to just create a new excel file.  Either write the template via code, or read in the template file and create new.  To debug this code, though, you want to see what exception was thrown.  So check that.

Comment: I can't really create a new one by the way the template is laid out. I do have the necessary cell and column info. Everything works except getting it to put the search data into the template.

Comment: with pandas you can easily append data to a csv file `df.to_csv('file.csv', mode='a', header=False)` (default mode is `'w'` (write))